# ForEach is repeating (duplicate results)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I'm trying to load some data from `mysql` but my code duplicates the results. My array should contain 2 objects with different info but I'm getting 4. I'm inside `module.exports`, I got 2 entries on MySQL.

```
let serverInfo = [];

loadInfo: function(){
        gm.mysql.handle.query('SELECT * FROM `info`', [], function(err, res, row){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            if(res.length){
                for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    res.forEach(function(zData){
                        
                        let id = zData.id;
                        let name = zData.name;
                        let color = zData.color;
                        let icon = zData.icon;
                        
                        serverInfo.push({id: id, name: name, color: color, icon: icon});
                        
                        if(name == "Server") {
                            name = "Server in use";
                        }
                        
                    });
                }
                // This code shows 4 results, the 2 existing on MySQL and another two.
                console.log("Loaded "+serverInfo.length+" servers.");
                console.log(serverInfo);
                /* This console log shows this
                [
                  {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Server',
                    color: 62,
                    icon: 50
                  },
                  {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Cloud',
                    color: 67,
                    icon: 3
                  },
                  {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Server',
                    color: 62,
                    icon: 50
                  },
                  {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Cloud',
                    color: 67,
                    icon: 3
                  }
                ]
                */
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You're calling it in a loop. Why *wouldn't* it repeat? You have `for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) 
 { res.forEach(/*...*/); }`, so you're calling `res.forEach` repeatedly, once for each value of `i`. Did you mean `res[i].forEach(/*...*/)`?

Comment: You have your `forEach` inside another `for` loop. the `for` loop is executing the `forEach` for every object in the `res`

Comment: I'm using the same code for another table and it loads correctly.

Comment: It will load correctly if the other table has a single row. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your for loop for this :

```
                for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {                            
                        const zData = res[i]                         
                        let id = zData.id;
                        let name = zData.name;
                        let color = zData.color;
                        let icon = zData.icon;
                        
                        serverInfo.push({id: id, name: name, color: color, icon: icon});
                        
                        if(name == "Server") {
                            name = "Server in use";
                        }
                        
                }
```

Comment: If I do that, I can't access to zData.

Comment: yes, i missed that part. I have made changes. Check if it works for you mate.

Comment: Good to hear that. @Hidro